# Add labels on circuits using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

1. Can I add a label on the top line with the name "vdd"?
2. A value for the current source?
3. The name of the transistor on the emitter line and add a number of devices where "Q_1" is?

.

```
\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}[american,node distance = 30pt]
    \draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to[Tpnp,name=Q1,l=$Q1$]
       ++(0,2) to[short]
       ++(0,2) node(v1){} to[I,invert,l^=$i_0$]
       ++(0,2)node[tground]{};    
    \draw (Q1.B) |- (0,0);
    \draw (v1) to[short] ++(1,0)node[below]{$v_D$} to[open,o-o]; 
    \end{circuitikz}
 \caption{The CTAT}
 \label{fig:CTAT}
 \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add the few code lines to make your example compilable? (On the other hand, you can remove the `figure` environment, as it is not relevant for the question.) Moreover, can you explain in more detail what you want to achieve, in particular question 2 and 3? Maybe add it by hand and attach a scan.

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of problems here (and an error in the last line; you need a coordinate after a `to` and you have none).

The labels on BJT, as explained on the manual, are quite pesky (I do not change them for backward compatibility) and it's better to put them by hand.

I suppose you want something like this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american,node distance = 30pt]
    \draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to[Tpnp,name=Q1]
       ++(0,2) to[short]
       ++(0,2) node(v1){} to[I,invert,l^=$i_0$]
       ++(0,2)node[tground](T){};
    \draw (Q1.B) |- (0,0);
    \draw (v1) to[short, -o] ++(1,0) node[below]{$v_D$};
    \path (Q1.east) node[right]{$Q_1$}; 
    \path (T.north) node[above]{$V_{dd}$}; 
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The new version of `circuitikz` will have the transistor's label position fixed. BTW, if this answer was useful for you, please consider [accepting it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)